# IOS/Objective-C: Track changes of multiple uitextfields as a batch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a large number of textfields on a screen and I want to detect which ones have changed and which ones have remained constant.  I can put action methods on them and check each individually but ideally as there can be up to 20, I'd like to have a batch method that does this all in one fell swoop when the person saves.

Right now I am collecting all the values in an array as follows:

```
 NSMutableArray <NSString*> *fieldText=[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:20];
    [fieldText addObject:_fieldOne.text];
    [fieldText addObject:_fieldTwo.text];//
etc.
```

However, the array although it collects all the values is not recording which have changed and which have not.  Each of the textfields relates to an object that has other attributes and if there are no changes, I'd like to leave the objects intact.

Is there a way to identify changed textfields simply for all textfields without tracking each individually?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Are your "20" textFields laid-out in IB, and connected via IBOutlet? Or are you creating them via code?

Comment: IB with outlets (@property *fieldone...).  The best method I have come up with is to collect them all in an array as above and then compare their values (NSStrings) to the original strings that I fetch from core data on load and store in aseparate array.  It is a bit klunky but the best I have come up with.